# Open problems in complexity theory

Tags: complexity-theory

I am looking for open problems in complexity theory that an undergrad might have any possibility of tackling.

Comment: Pick a random problem, then prove its hardness. I'm a fan of game/puzzle reductions myself, picking a popular mobile game and then proving (a generalization of) it NP-complete is bound to give you something that hasn't been done before and that should be achievable for an undergrad. If you don't find any suitable problems this way you could also take some known (hard) problem and look at its parameterized complexity.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Comment: there are problems that undergrads could _attack_ or _experiment_ with... drop by to [chat] for discussions... a good answer would depend on your own bkg/ interests/ dedication...